# bitmap not saving image to memory stream

Tags: c#, memory, bitmap, stream, bitmapimage

Need a little help here. I have a app that I am creating that mergies two pictures together. The issue is when i am trying to convert the bitmap into a bitmpaimage to display the result on the screen. from what i can tell, the image is not being save to the memory stream at "NwImg.Save(memory,ImageFormat.Jpeg);" Any ideas??

```
 //The Code   
    //bitmap to bitmapimage conversion
            using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
            {//NwImg is type Bitmap, and at this point i checked properties and values did copy over from the merging
                NwImg.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Jpeg);//here image NwImg.save is suppose to transfer to memory
                memory.Position = 0;
                Nwbi.StreamSource = memory;//memory stream is showing null
                Nwbi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;

            }
```

I don't know if this matter but NwImg represents a bitmap that was created by merging a png image on top of a jpeg. I didn't read anything that said it matter but i figured i would through that in there.

/// here is all the code as requested david
//Main c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;


namespace PicMerger2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Pic currentPic = new Pic();
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri("\\original photo.jpg"));
        BitmapImage Nwbi = new BitmapImage();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            OriginalPhoto.Source = bi;
            ResultPhoto.Source = Nwbi;

        }

        private void apply_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap NwImg;
            //bitmapimage to bitmap conversion
            using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                BitmapEncoder enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
                enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bi));
                enc.Save(outStream);
                System.Drawing.Bitmap MarkThisPic = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(outStream);

                // return bitmap; <-- leads to problems, stream is closed/closing ...
                NwImg = new Bitmap(MarkThisPic);
            }
            NwImg = currentPic.MergerTheseTwo(NwImg);


            //bitmap to bitmapimage conversion
            using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                NwImg.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                memory.Position = 0;
                Nwbi.StreamSource = memory;
                Nwbi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;

            }
            ResultPhoto.Source = Nwbi;
        }
    }
}
```

//Main xaml

```
<Window x:Class="PicMerger2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image x:Name="OriginalPhoto" Height="200" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="{Binding}"></Image>
                <Label>Original Images</Label>
            </StackPanel>
            <Button x:Name="apply" Click="apply_Click" Height="25" >Apply Watermark</Button>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image x:Name="ResultPhoto" Height="200" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="{Binding}"></Image>
                <Label>Watermarked Image</Label>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

// pic class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace PicMerger2
{
    class Pic
    {
        Bitmap Watermark = new Bitmap(PicMerger2.Properties.Resources._Watermark);


        public Bitmap MergerTheseTwo(Bitmap BottomImage)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var canvas = Graphics.FromImage(BottomImage))
                {
                    canvas.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    //       canvas.DrawImage(BottomImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, BottomImage.Width, BottomImage.Height), new Rectangle(0, 0, BottomImage.Width, BottomImage.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    canvas.DrawImage(Watermark, 0, 0);
                    canvas.Save();

                    //Save to current picture
                    Bitmap NewImage = new Bitmap(BottomImage.Width, BottomImage.Height, canvas);
                    return NewImage;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that merges the images?

Comment: In your `apply_Click`, you don't rewind `outStream` before you create a bitmap from it. That could be a problem. Also, I suspect that if you put the line `ResultPhoto.Source = Nwbi;` inside the preceding `using` block, things will start to work. Just a guess. I think the memory stream is being disposed before the image is actually loaded from it.

Comment: Hey Jim, what is 'rewind'? Looked at the memorystream class on msdn and didn't see anything about rewind http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx also I tracked the values in debugging and the issue is within the using statement, see first code block above.

Comment: "rewind" means seeking back to the beginning of the file. Setting the position to 0. Was a common term back when computer storage was on tape and seeking to the beginning of the file required rewinding the tape. It kind of stuck around. Or maybe it's finally gone from the lexicon.

Comment: What does "memory stream is showing null" mean? Are you saying that if you inspect the variable `memory`, it's showing `null`? That seems ... highly unlikely. Please explain.

Comment: Well please feel free to try the code, I just moved the line 'ResultPhoto.Source = Nwbi; inside the using statement but it still doesn't show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change a couple of things so that your code can work.

1. Use the following code for the Bitmap to BitmapImage conversion.

   ```
   using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
   {
       NwImg.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
       memory.Position = 0;
       Nwbi = new BitmapImage();
       Nwbi.BeginInit();
       Nwbi.StreamSource = memory;
       Nwbi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
       Nwbi.EndInit();
   }
   ```
2. Inside your Pic class, replace these lines

   ```
   //Save to current picture
   Bitmap NewImage = new Bitmap(BottomImage.Width, BottomImage.Height, canvas);
   return NewImage;
   ```

   to this

   ```
   return BottomImage;
   ```

   since the overload of the Bitmap class that you are using, doesn't create a new bitmap based on the Graphics object but just its resolution (this results to an empty image). So, since you draw onto the BottomImage bitmap, you just need to return that image.

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH DAVID!!!!! IT WORKS!!!!! I will have to read more about images, i really don't know from reading the libraries that that is what graphic did. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The variable "memory" cannot possibly be null on the line where you commented "memory stream is showing null" when that line executes because it is definitely assigned in the "using" block 4 lines above it.  I'm guessing you put a debugger breakpoint too early in the method.  Try putting your breakpoint on the line where you assign `Nwbi.CacheOption` and see if the debugger tells you what you expected.

Comment: It is null. I first ran it with no breaks and notice image didn't update, then I when backwards through code and ran it several times and at this point is where I lose image, Nwbi shows null outside of using